# CMPXCHG16B and MSVC Implementation of <atomic> not the default?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, x86-64, stdatomic, compare-and-swap

It seems that for CMPXCHG16B to be used, one has to define _STD_ATOMIC_ALWAYS_USE_CMPXCHG16B = 1
so that these instructions are used.

Why is this the default? I would have never found out about this unless I read the whole atomic.h header either.

What other global defines in the STL are there? Is there a list to review so one can reliably be aware of these implementation details?

Comment: What version of `atomic` are you looking at? In my VC++ 2019 `_STD_ATOMIC_ALWAYS_USE_CMPXCHG16B` only occurs inside an `#if 0` block.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/187254/how-prevalent-are-old-x64-processors-lacking-the-cmpxchg16b-instruction

Comment: Note that doing this is not ABI-compatible with other code using `atomic<16byte_object>`.  All code touching an object needs to agree whether to use a separate lock or not.

Comment: using msvc 16.8.2, it's not inside of a #if 0 block

Comment: @J.Tully Interesting. It's still inside an `#if 0 // TRANSITION, ABI` block in 16.7.5 which is the [current](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2019-v16-7-releases/) VS 2019 [long-term servicing release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/servicing).

Comment: It isn't part of STL (Standard Template Library).

Answer (score 6):

`_STD_ATOMIC_ALWAYS_USE_CMPXCHG16B` was recently introduced in Visual Studio 2019 (the [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/pull/843))

Visual Studio 2019 still supports older OSes such as Windows Vista, and Windows 7. These OSes can run on old AMD Opteron CPUs that don't have this instruction.

Even if `_STD_ATOMIC_ALWAYS_USE_CMPXCHG16B = 0`, there's runtime detection that uses `CMPXCHG16B` if it is available. But in this case the instructions is not inlined, and there's also a branch, so it is less efficient than defining `_STD_ATOMIC_ALWAYS_USE_CMPXCHG16B = 1`.

Please also note that `CMPXCHG16B` is used for `atomic_ref`, but not for `atomic` due to ABI compatibility. (It was possible to introduce for `atomic_ref`, since there was no pre-C++20 `atomic_ref` to be ABI-compatible with).

In `vNext` version (the next major, ABI breaking version), `atomic` should use `CMPXCHG16B` as well. There's also hope that old CPUs/OSes support will be dropped, and the use of `CMPXCHG16B` would become unconditional. (See https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/1151).

> I would have never found out about this unless I read the whole atomic.h header either.

> What other global defines in the STL are there? Is there a list to review so one can reliably be aware of these implementation details?

I'm afraid there's no comprehensive list, although some are documented.

The excuse for `_STD_ATOMIC_ALWAYS_USE_CMPXCHG16B` in particular could be that whole `atomic_ref` is not documented, and as C++20 feature it has *experimental* status in Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: great answer! I'm using CMPXCHG16B for __m128 & __m128i datatypes. The atomic compare exchange of __m128 is particularly useful. The performance however is a fraction of the same code that uses a single atomic integer. An __m128 is naturally aligned to 16bytes correct?

Comment: See [the documentation on __m128](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/m128) on answer about alignment: _Variables of type __m128 are automatically aligned on 16-byte boundaries_